# How can have two div's appear after clicking a div link?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, html

Hello there I have a few questions.
I am trying to make my clickable div links make a div popup with the link  inside, while also having information on a side about the  link inside of the div.

```
<html>
<title>lc</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
<div class="screen">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head><body>
<div class="left_index"><p><a href="http:/l_c/index.php">lc</a></p></div>
<?php
echo('<iframe src="' . $mysquaresarray[$randomno] . '" width="700" height="709" align="center" frameBorder="0"></iframe>');
?>
```

My Css is

```
.screen{
            position:absolute;
            width:800px;
            height:800px;

    }

    .left_index{
            position:relative;
            top:20px;
            left:80px;
            font-family: Futura, Optima, sans-serif; 
            font-size:30px; 
            margin:0px 0px, 0px,0px; 
            font-weight: thin; 
            }
```

Here is an example of what would be fed in to the iframe:

```
#four{  
                bottom: 175px;
                left: 300px;
                height:90px;
                width:90px;
                    }
            #four a {
            display: block;
               height:90px;
               width:90px;
        }

        #five{
                bottom: 100px;
                left: 150px;
                height:90px;
                width:90px;
            }
            #five a {
            display: block;
               height:90px;
               width:90px;
        }


    <div id="four"><a href="/course/s12pudt_2101e/projects/holden/Project5a/WEC.php" target="_blank" display:block;></a> </div>
    <div id="five"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fivetwo"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqca9uKPeSg&feature=endscreen&NR=1" target="_blank"         display:block;></a> </div>
    </body>
        </html>
```

Thank you very much.
Inside of the iframe are html pages that are randomly genrerated. The html pages all contain divs that are clickable. I would like to click these div's and have the html page that it is linked to popup inside of a div and have another div popup with information about the page.

EDIT:How would I start writing the code for this? 
I used the slideToggle function as a professor suggested, but I'm not sure how to get it to work for my div links inside of my iframe.
Can anyone help me do this?
How would I go about it

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, I think you wrote it in a rush.
I would focus on writing one js function to help you with that.
Also, why using iFrames? I would get the html via AJAX instead.

Comment: btw.... you can use lightbox or colorbox (jQuery) plugins for that, I think its exacly what you need.

Comment: You don't seem to have included an actual question in your post, except "Is is it possible?" to which I would say "Yes". Is there something specific that you're stuck on?

Comment: Also how would you suggest getting the html pages via AJAX, I've never used it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.get( "urlpath/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".resultdiv" ).html( data ); 
});
```

For cross origin requests :

```
 $.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      $( ".resultdiv" ).html( data );
    }
});
```